# Book to learn Darboux integral

Tags: real-analysis, integration, reference-request

What are some good references to ,  good book to learn Darboux integral ( https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Darboux_integral     ) ? Please help .

Comment: This topic is so often treated together with Riemann integration that the best thing to do, if you want to assemble a lot of facts and examples relating to Darboux integrals, is to flip through a lot of real analysis texts where Riemann integration is discussed and take notes and/or photocopy the things you find interesting. A large university library would be ideal for this, if one is available to you. **(continued)**

Comment: **(continuation)**  If I had to recommend one book (without having the chance to look over my stuff at home, which I can't do right now), it would probably be Karl Stromberg's [**Introduction to Classical Real Analysis**](http://www.amazon.com/dp/0534980120). The prices seem to me excessive (and the "new" prices seem so high as to likely be an error), but the book is widely available in college and university libraries, so it should be possible to get a copy by interlibrary loan if it is not available in a nearby library.

Comment: A Garden of Integrals, by Frank E. Burk is very useful

Answer (score 2):

Calculus by Spivak, any edition. He uses Darboux for the whole chapter on integration. He is vague in his explanations though.

Answer (score 0):

You should try Introduction to Real Analysis by S. K. Mapa. It uses Darboux Integrals to explain Riemann Integral completely. Overall it's an awesome book. Thank you.